# The head content appearing in body tag

Tags: php, zend-framework2

im quite new to ZF2 and ive got the following problem.
The  contents (meta, scrips, css etc.) appearing twice.
above the  tag and inside the  tag.

[image: screenshot]

but i dont see where its injected.

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this on a certain page, or all pages?

Comment: only the one. thats why i dont understand why this is happening.

Comment: Right click in browser and select 'view source'(NOT inspect element). What do you get

Comment: alright. ive got also two body tags. it seems that there are two layouts rendering the page. thank i will try out myself first :)

Answer (score 0):

OK.
in my module.config.php there was

```
'frontend/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
```

which was rendering the layout twice. thanks for the hint